# Compatibility files folder in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

In Windows 7 if an installed application attempts to write files in its application folder under *Program Files*, the files are actually written into a *Compatibility files* folder and in explorer you can navigate to this folder by pressing the *Compatibility files* button from inside the application folder.

In Windows 8 though I no longer see the *Compatibility files* button. Has this functionality been changed in Windows 8? Or is there some other way of navigating to this folder in Windows 8? If it is the case that there is no *Compatibility files* folder in Windows 8, how does Windows 8 handle the situation of an application attempting to write files to its application folder under *Program Files*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't been able to find anything concrete from Microsoft on this, but the consensus seems to be that the *Compatibility files* button is gone from Windows 8.

The virtual store (where these files would be located) is in the same place in Windows 8. You can navigate to it at `%LocalAppData%\VirtualStore`.

Comment: That was the info I needed. Perfect. Thanks for your help, Toryan.

Answer (score -2):

You can also just change the location of the game folder to get it right over intoo The Char file in the game folder i reccomend (Sorry if i spelled that wrong)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common
(if you have steam)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an actual answer to the question, sorry. If you have something to add, please [edit] your post.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question and in fact has nothing to do with the question asked.