# How to use "dir" to show hidden files that "ls" shows just fine?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I have a oximetry viewer software, it secretly stores data under its Data directory.

To explain this:
There was nothing shown up in Explorer. But with the oximetry reader program, everything shows up:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcjBN.png]

There's plenty of ways to hide files, but this is interesting:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SpO2\Data>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 3A3C-8424

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\SpO2\Data

2015-06-13  11:46 AM    <DIR>          .
2015-06-13  11:46 AM    <DIR>          ..
2011-06-10  01:45 AM                 0 this-dir-intentionally-left-blank
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  517,778,055,168 bytes free
```

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SpO2\Data>dir /a:h
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 3A3C-8424

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\SpO2\Data

File Not Found
```

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SpO2\Data>dir /a:hs
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 3A3C-8424

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\SpO2\Data

File Not Found
```

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SpO2\Data>dir /r
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 3A3C-8424

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\SpO2\Data

2015-06-13  11:46 AM    <DIR>          .
2015-06-13  11:46 AM    <DIR>          ..
2011-06-10  01:45 AM                 0 this-dir-intentionally-left-blank
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  517,777,969,152 bytes free
```

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SpO2\Data>ls
qzhou_201505281948.csv       qzhou_201506060647.csv
qzhou_201505281948.spo       qzhou_201506060647.spoR
qzhou_201505281948_wave.csv  qzhou_201506070726.csv
qzhou_201505281955.csv       qzhou_201506070726.spoR
qzhou_201505281955.spoR      qzhou_201506080642.csv
qzhou_201505311018.csv       qzhou_201506080642.spoR
qzhou_201505311018.spoR      qzhou_201506100816.csv
qzhou_201506040657.csv       qzhou_201506100816.spoR
qzhou_201506040657.spoR      qzhou_201506131146.csv
qzhou_201506050727.csv       qzhou_201506131146.spoR
qzhou_201506050727.spoR      this-dir-intentionally-left-blank
```

Maybe it's NTFS files stream? So I tried with [LADS](http://www.heysoft.de/en/software/lads.php), but nothing shows up:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SpO2\Data>lads /A

LADS - Freeware version 4.10
(C) Copyright 1998-2007 Frank Heyne Software (http://www.heysoft.de)
This program lists files with alternate data streams (ADS)
Use LADS on your own risk!

Scanning directory C:\Program Files (x86)\SpO2\Data\

      size  ADS in file
----------  ---------------------------------

         0 bytes in 0 ADS listed
   2803988 bytes (uncompressed) used by C:\Program Files (x86)\SpO2\Data\

999655731200 total bytes on this disk
517764317184 free bytes on this disk
```

I am confused :S, how is this possible, if it's not there, `dir` and `ls` should give the same empty output, but `ls` actually gave the correct answer.

Windows 8.1 Update 1.

Comment: How about `dir /a`?

Comment: Now that you know the file name, isn't there some command to show file attributes and all? And does `ls -l` show some interesting details? And: is `ls` included in Windows nowadays; if not: which `ls` are you using?

Comment: @PetSerAl dir /a has the same output as dir, nothing just `this-dir-intentionally-left-blank`

Comment: @Arjan ls -la gives nothing special, for instance "-rw-r--r--    1 qzhou    Administ    55858 Jun 13 11:47 qzhou_201506131146.spoR", no marks, no links. The `ls` I used is from fileutils 4.1, from the github installer, I believe.

Comment: @QuanZhou: Read [this](https://u-tools.com/msls.htm#64bit) and [this](https://u-tools.com/msls.htm#virtual) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not explain how to use `dir` in that folder, but [Importing CMS 50D Plus oximeter data into SleepyHead](http://www.apneaboard.com/wiki/index.php?title=Importing_CMS_50D_Plus_oximeter_data_into_SleepyHead#Other_Information:) claims Windows Explorer has a "Compatibility files" button, in Windows 7 (but apparently not in Windows 8):

> To "unhide" them, go to where the files should be. Usually, this is *Program Files > SpO2 > Data* or *Program Files (x86)> SpO2 > Data*. Click the "Compatibility" button near the top. It should be next to the "New Folder" button. This will "unhide" the files. You will need to do this each time you want to view them.
>
> [image]

Also, there is some folder called "Virtual Store", which also works in Windows 8:

> To view directly, go to users > (user name) > AppData > Local > Virtual Store > Program Files (x86) > SPO2 > Data
>
> [image]

Maybe the `dir` command would work in that folder?

As for the origin of this folder, [Compatibility files folder in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/626465/compatibility-files-folder-in-windows-8) explains that software cannot create files in their own application folder:

> In Windows 7 if an installed application attempts to write files in its application folder under *Program Files*, the files are actually written into a *Compatibility files* folder [...]

Comment: I can't find the "Compatibility files" button on Windows 8.1 anymore, according to this http://superuser.com/questions/626465/compatibility-files-folder-in-windows-8 , I can now find the files in the virtual store. Many thanks for the hint!